# Casting Issues in Swift

Tags: swift

I have two UICollectionViewCells and I want to differentiate between the two. My RetroItemCollectionViewCell has a method called "configureFor". For some reason even if I cast it I am not able to call the "configureFor" function.

```
 var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)

        if cell is RetroItemCollectionViewCell {

            cell = cell as! RetroItemCollectionViewCell
            let retroItem = self.retroItems[indexPath.row]
            cell.configureFor(retroItem: retroItem)

        } else if cell is RetroItemAddCollectionViewCell {

        }
```

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

```
var cell :UICollectionViewCell!

// check if the cell is the add cell
if indexPath.row == 0 {

    cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: addRetroItemCollectionViewCellReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! RetroItemAddCollectionViewCell


} else {

    // HOW DO I CONVERT THE cell to RetroItemCollectionViewCell

    let retroItem = self.retroItems[indexPath.row]

    cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! RetroItemCollectionViewCell

}
```

Comment: `if let cell = cell as? RetroItemCollectionViewCell {`

Comment: `is` doesn't cast a variable, it merely runtime-checks whether or not a variable is of a specific type.

Comment: But I am using as inside the is

Comment: I just updated the code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're searching for the `as?` operator

> The as? operator performs a conditional cast of the expression to the specified type. The as? operator returns an optional of the specified type. At runtime, if the cast succeeds, the value of expression is wrapped in an optional and returned; otherwise, the value returned is nil. [- Swift Language Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH32-ID385)

```
var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)

if let cell as? RetroItemCollectionViewCell {
    let retroItem = self.retroItems[indexPath.row]
    cell.configureFor(retroItem: retroItem)
} else if let cell as? RetroItemAddCollectionViewCell {
    // ...
}
```